# Can you explain error when passing a query formula to a variable

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function which should pass a formula to a sheet.  The script works well for an ordinary formula but when the formula is query I get an error "missing ; before statement ( line 59...)   Here is a snip of the error and code - line 59 ends ....";
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem is caused by the nesting of quotes

The correct way to nest is

- either to alternate single and double quotes

> Sample:

`var form1='QUERY(A2:E6,"select avg(A) pivot B", -1)';`

- or to escape the inner quotes with a backslash:

> Sample:

`var form1="QUERY(A2:E6,\"select avg(A) pivot B\", -1)";`

See also [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp).

Comment: I hope it worked for you. If you found it helpful, please consider accepting it to increase visibility for other users who might encounter the same problem.